# How can i read from an ArrayList<> to an ArrayList<> and make it print to the terminal?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a monopoly type game and this is the second question i make on this problem i have. I a Board class and a Square class. In my main class i am creating squares using a method in my Board class called `addSquare` and then this method stores info about the certain square on the Square class. After that i am trying to read a certain square from the Board class in the `getSquare` method but i don't know how to do that.

I am providing a test solution i made only for testing the board mechanics:

The Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Board board = new Board();

        Action act = new Action();

        board.addSquare("0,Country in conflict.", act);

        board.getSquare(0);
    }
}
```

The Board class:

```
 public class Board {

    public ArrayList<Square> Board;

    public Board(){
        this.Board = new ArrayList<Square>();
    }

    public void addSquare(String square, Action action){
        Square sq = new Square(square, action);
        Board.add(sq);
    }

    public void addSquare(String square, Action action1, Action action2){
        Square sq = new Square(square, action1, action2);
        Board.add(sq);
    }

    public void getSquare(int square){
        Board.get(square);
    }
}
```

The Square Class:

```
 public class Square{

    public ArrayList<Action> actions;
    public final String text;
    public final int squareNumber;

    public Square(String textGiven, Action action){
        String textArray[] = textGiven.split(",");
        this.squareNumber = Integer.parseInt(textArray[0]);
        this.text = textArray[1];
        this.actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        actions.add(action);
    }

    public Square(String textGiven, Action action1, Action action2){
        String textArray[] = textGiven.split(",");
        this.squareNumber = Integer.parseInt(textArray[0]);
        this.text = textArray[1];
        this.actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        actions.add(action1);
        actions.add(action2);
    }

    public Action getAction(Action action){
        return action;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return squareNumber;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    public String toSrting(){
        return squareNumber + ". " + text;
    }
}
```

Note: wherever is says Action is a separate class for the actions the player needs to do. I have the class correctly so thats why i am not providing info but if it is needed to i will update with the code of the Action class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` here returns a `Square`, but you are not making use of it at all:

```
public void getSquare(int square){
    Board.get(square);
}
```

Like all the other `getXXX` methods, `getSquare` should return a value:

```
public Square getSquare(int square){
    return Board.get(square);
}
```

And you print the returned value by `System.out.println`, as you probably know already:

```
System.out.println(board.getSquare(0));
```

I also noticed that you misspelled `toString`:

```
public String toSrting(){ // <----
    return squareNumber + ". " + text;
}
```

This is why you should always add `@Override` when overriding methods. It outputs an error if the method you are trying to override doesn't exist, essentially checking your spelling for you.

Comment: i have already tried that and it prints out this message:
board.square.test.Square@129a8472

Comment: @Kamora you misspelled `toString` in `Square`.

Comment: oh man yes your are right... i have spent hours for this project and those silly mistakes happen when your head goes crazy and not focus on simple things...

Comment: I just did!
Thanks again for your help!